# VSCode дзен режим (Zen mode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как включить Дзен режим (Zen Mode) Visual Studio Code?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zen Mode (Дзен-режим) скрывает все панели и оставляет только код. Помогает сосредоточиться на задаче.

Горячие клавиши

1. Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> (отпустите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> перед нажатием <kbd>Z</kbd>)
2. OS X <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

Через `Command Palette`

1. <kbd>F1</kbd> или Win:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> или OS X:<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. В строку ввести `zen`
3. Выбрать: `View: Toogle Zen Mode`

Через интерфейс `VSCode`: `View` -> `Appearance` -> `Zen Mode`

##### Как выйти из Zen mode

1. Дважды нажать <kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. Воспользоваться `Command Palette`
3. Воспользоваться горячими клавишами

Comment: Через интерфейс: View -> Appearance -> Zen Mode (Вид -> Внешний вид -> Режим Zen)

Comment: @harpCS спасибо, добавил